# the problem loading the request app in react native

Tags: react-native, lan

Im getting following react native connecting issues

Im getting error while running my expo app in my mobile i have tried some

network tricks but that did not work please suggest me the solution

this is the image

Comment: kindly share error message and image. Also more elaborate your issue

Comment: there was a problem loading the requested app.it looks like you may be using a lan url.make sure your device is on the same network as the server or try using a tunnel this is the error message